# When reading a BSB/KAP chart file, I am getting incorrect run lengths. Many runs lengths are way too long

Tags: raster, java, chart, noaa

My java code for reading the run length portion of the stream is shown below. The run lengths being read in don't make sense.

```
byte b =  (byte) br.read(); //read a byte from the stream
                    eol = (b == 0);             // if it is a null, that marks the end of line
                    if (eol) break;
                    pixel = (byte) ((b & 0x7F) >> 3);   //mask out the concatenate bit, and shift 4 bit color index to bottom of byte
                    multiplier = b & maskingMultiplier; //save the top 3 repeat bits from the 1st byte of pixel
                    // if the concatenate bit is set, there is more repeat bits for this pixel
                    while ((b & 0x80) == 0x80)
                    {   b = (byte) br.read();
                        multiplier = (multiplier << 7) + (b & 0X7F);
                    }
```

What is wrong with this code, or am I misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: as an example, an input line is "01 FD FD 47 00". this chart has a line length of 8520. The line indicates a single white pixel with a repeat count of 97991. ??

Comment: Do you mean this format https://legacy.iho.int/mtg_docs/com_wg/HSSC/HSSC3/S-64_Edition_2.0.0/RNC_Test_Data_Sets/BSB_TDS/BSB_Test_Dataset_Instructions_for_RNC.pdf?

Comment: Yes, I am using this spec: BSB File Format Version 3.0, Revision 3.0.7, August 2000. And the input line mentioned above is from the NOAA RNC #18456, "Olympia Harbor and Budd Inlet".  I have the line and pixel scanning working, the run lengths just aren't working for some reason.

Comment: excerpt  : Each line of raster image data is encoded as follows LineNumber Color 1, Run 1 ... Color n, Run n NULL
LineNumber = Sequential line count encoded in the MSB
concatenation scheme.
Top line = 1.
Color, Run: Coded in accordance with the format selection, in
the NOS compression scheme.
The sum of the runs on a line
= the line width.
NULL: Binary 0 value used to signify line termination.

Comment: another line, # 43 in the chart, consists of a long white section, a short black section, and a short white section. In this line the sum of the runs is 196,667 (again the line length is 8520.

Comment: I think all that I can do is to point to this BSB reader code https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/bsb/bsb_read.c. Unfortunately I mostly understand just the comments but they are entertaining.

Comment: Your post is a little sketchy on details.  But I wonder if your line that gives multiplier = b & maskingMultiplier; //save the top 3 repeat bits from the 1st byte of pixel  should actually be saving the three lowest order bits from the pixel.

Comment: Is your maskingMultiplier equal to 0000_0111 or 1110_0000?

Comment: Gary, it is  byte maskingMultiplier = (byte) 0b00000111; I am using 4 bit color charts so only the bottom three bits of the first byte is the multiplier part. thanks.

Comment: user30184, thanks I read that code and the author does take steps to check for too long run lengths. it looks like he cuts the length down : if( iPixel + nRunCount + 1 > psInfo->nXSize )
                nRunCount = psInfo->nXSize - iPixel - 1;

Comment: I have an older version of Chart 18456, so I can't verify your results.  And the chart I looked at has a width of 10168,  But one thing that does occur to me is that maybe your answer is correct.  A nautical chart has a white margin and a "collar" around the chart area.  97991 pixels is only about 11 lines.  Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: Gary, That might be right, I will look into some lines of the actual chart instead of around the collar. And see if the run lengths make any more sense. FWIW, I am using in previous version of app the PDF version that NOAA publishes. By loading this PDF into Photoshop at 400 DPI, and trimming the borders off at the pixels indicated by the georeferencing information in the related KAP file, then downscaling , I do get a correctly georeferenced chart image I can show in my tide app. But it is not ideal, there is a lot of hand work, and I lose full resolution display. Larry - tide.now@gmail.com

Comment: Larry, downloaded the latest version of 18456 from NOAA and looked at the file 18546_1.KAP.  Running my BSB reader, it appears that row 1 starts at file offset 21430 (it is preceded by header information).  On row 1, I get pixel value of 2 and a run-length of 8520 (don't forget to add one to the value obtained from the bytes, there is no such thing as a zero run length in RNC).   Bytes read from start of row are 0x01, 0x90, 0xc2, 0x47,

Answer (score 1):

The Raster Nautical Chart format uses a KAP file to supply the chart. The file includes textual information for chart name, number, geographic referencing, etc.

The file also includes binary information to directly convey the chart pixel information by rows and columns. Drawing instructions use a run length for each pixel to eliminate redundant information. It is a very efficient storage method using a palletized pixel arrangement.

The binary section follows the text section. In my Android/Java app, I read the text information by accessing the file using java BufferedReader in conjunction with InputStreamReader. But to read the binary section I read the file using a BufferedInputStream. In this step I scan the binary file for an ASCII End of File character followed by a NULL character. Following that is the Bits per Pixel code, then the rows and columns of pixels follow.

I originally tried to use the BufferedReader for the entire read, but after the binary section is entered then I was getting incorrect byte data in some locations. I am not a Java expert but I have been told that BufferedReader is good for text information but the BufferedInputStream is good for binary files. My experience bears that out.

Answer (score 0):

I posted some of this information as a comment, but I think maybe it should be treated as an answer, so I hope you'll excuse the repetition.

My guess is that you are reading data from the wrong file position.  The BSB format has a couple of files, the one with the extension KAP gives the image data. The beginning of the file is all textual data in ASCII format.  Then end of the text is given by the byte value 26.  It is followed by a zero and then a byte giving the image depth.  Then the first row starts.

I downloaded the latest version of chart 18456 from NOAA and looked at the file 18546_1.KAP. The image is 8520 pixels wide and 15326 pixels high. Running my BSB reader, it appears that row 1 starts at file offset 21430 (it is preceded by header information). On row 1, I get pixel value of 2 (which maps to white) and a run-length of 8520 (don't forget to add one to the value obtained from the bytes, there is no such thing as a zero run length in RNC). Bytes read from start of row are 0x01, 0x90, 0xc2, 0x47.

I am uploading a JPG I built from a somewhat older version of the chart so you can see what to expect from the chart collar.  The header information describes a bounding polygon which, in Java, you can use to define a clipping polygon as a Path2D and remove the collar when rendering.

The URL for the source RNC data was https://charts.noaa.gov/RNCs/RNCsIndv.shtml

I regret that I cannot share my BSB code with you, but it is proprietary to my employer.  But I hope that this information helps.

Gary

[image]

At the risk of straying too far from GIS and into Java coding territory, here's an example that I used:

```
    File inputFile = new File("18456_1.KAP");

    try (FileInputStream fins = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            BufferedInputStream bins = new BufferedInputStream(fins);) {
        int n = 0;
        int b;
        while ((b = bins.read()) >= 0) {
            if (b == 26) {
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println("Found binary-section after " + n + " bytes");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.format("  0x%02x", bins.read());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
    }
```

Comment: Gary thank you I will study this today and check my input file.

Comment: I'm finding the binary section by looking for the end of the text section which is EOF, NULL, and the IFM code (4). I verify that then start the binary section which is still as reported above first line is 01 FD FD 47, then next line is 02 FD FD 47, etc for many more. I did download a new KAP file and tried that instead. same.  thanks I cannot verify the file offset you mentioned will try again later.

Comment: IS EOF actually equivalent to ASCII 26 (CTRL-Z)?  I did some poking around, and I don't see that abbreviation used anywhere associated with the value 26, at least not in Java.  But I guess it would depend on your context (I did see it in some discussion of old OS's).   Maybe I didn't look in the right place.  In any case, I might recommend try specifically coding to 26 and seeing what happens.

Comment: Gary, Here is a hex dump of where that KAP file transitions from text to binary: 0D 0A 1A 00 04 01 90 C2 47 00 02 90 C2 47 00     that is carriage return , line feed, end of file, null, the 04 is the bits per pixel, then the first scan line commences 01 90 C2 47 00 more lines follow. I need to use a utility to read a binary file instead of a text file which is what the code shows. I'm reading the right place with the wrong tool THANK YOU GARY!

Comment: I just modified my answer to include some Java code. If you are just reading the image file sequentially, a BufferedInputStream might be as good a solution as any.

Comment: I think maybe what went wrong is first I started reading the file as lines of text. I did that to read out the information such as number of lines, line length, etc. I then switched to reading just bytes to get the contents of binary portion of the file. Maybe that confused the input routine br.read() and it started adjusting what it was giving me. I am now working to change the code to keep the two sequences separate, so i will get pure data again. I'll find out tomorrow morning as I complete this step. ? Never know thanks again Gary Lucas!

Comment: After reading the text strings, I close the file and reopen it using a BufferedInputStream which is more suitable for binary files. I am now reading the run lengths correctly and at last getting a recognizable display.